# Fetching logo from the company url in android

Tags: android

My problem statement is to fetch the company logo from the company website.I have the input as the company website url. How can we fetch the company logo from it.I need to implement it in Android App.
For Example I have a Edittextbox with button.When user enter the text in the edittextbox i.e. the company's url eg www.google.com.So when user clicks on search I need to display the company logo i.e. the logo of the google.How can I achieve this in android

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: So what exactly is the question you've got? Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to ask a question

Comment: I have editted the question

Comment: There is no standard for where a "company logo" is on a Web site. Given the URL to the site, you have no means of deriving a URL to a "company logo". At most, you can load the HTML of the home page and see if there is a `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">`.

Answer (score 2):

Use Glide :

//app build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

  Glide.with(this)
        .load(yourEdittext.getText().toString) //Edit
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .signature(new StringSignature(UUID.randomUUID().toString())) //use this 
        .into(imgView);
```

Comment: please check the question again

Comment: did you get it brother?

Comment: You have used Picasso which is similar to Glide! Anyway best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Use picasso or glide library for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with just a url to a domain. You need a specific url to a image for libraries such as picasso or glide to work. Because every site has different html code, you have to first find the logo in the html, which is quite impossible since not every site is the same. If you know the image url of your company, just use that url and use a library as suggested.

Comment: Sir there can be any way we can fetch the logo.

Comment: So show us how you can fetch the url for your logo.

Comment: Sir please check my answer and thanks for the motivation you provided.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I have tried to fetch the logo.I have used JSoup library to read the html page source code.
In that I have called link element of html.After getting all the link element I checked for the icon.From there I got the href of the logo and after getting the source I am done with my logo finding.

```
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

        import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
        import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
        import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
        import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

        import java.io.IOException;

       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     String url="";
    EditText editText;
    ImageView imageView;
    Button button;
    TextView textView;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(editText.getText().toString()!=null && !editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    String temp=editText.getText().toString();
                    if(temp!=null && !temp.isEmpty())
                    {
                        String divide[]=temp.split("\\.");
                        url="http://www."+divide[divide.length-2]+"."+divide[divide.length-1];
                    }
                }
               new Title().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                if(url!=null && !url.isEmpty()) {
                    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                    // Get the html document title
                    Elements description = document.select("link");
                    title = description.attr("href");
                    for (Element metaElem : description) {
                        String name = metaElem.attr("rel");
                        if (name.contains("icon")) {
                            title = metaElem.attr("href");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            //TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            textView.setText(title);
            String imageURL=textView.getText().toString();
            if(!textView.getText().toString().contains("http"))
            {
                String c=imageURL;
                c=c.substring(0,1);
                if(!c.equals("/"))
                {
                  imageURL=url+"/"+imageURL;
                }
                else
                {
                    imageURL=url+imageURL;
                }
            }
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(imageURL)
                    .error(R.drawable.down_arrow)
                    .into(imageView);
                    //this is optional the image to display while the url image is downloading
            //this is also optional if some error has occurred in downloading the image this image would be displayed

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```